# При создание нового проекта в AS появляется ошибка "cannot resolve symbol R"

Tags: android-studio

Всем привет.

Только начал осваивать AS. И сразу после установки столкнулся с такой проблемой.

При создание нового проекта в Android Studio или добавление модуля, в файле active сразу появляется ошибка R ("cannot resolve symbol R"). Из-за этого при эмулирование проекта, эмулятор лежит пустой, а любой скрипт не работает. 
[image: cannot resolve symbol R]
Я гуглил этот вопрос и узнал, что в путях к папкам .android.gradle не должно быть символов кириллицы в пути. Но как перенести эти папки, а потом указать обновлённые пути в AS я не понял

С другой стороны, ошибки вроде не указывают на путь к этим папкам
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, если кто знает как побороть эту ошибку, или перенести эти папки в другой каталог - подскажите мне)

[Ссылка на логи](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1q9TEA-qnK0qimnTSrDViXCIqTyY4AMPW?usp=sharing)

UPD: Build-> clean project - пробовал в первую очередь. Не помогает. Проект не импортируется, а создаётся. Может быть разницы и нет. Но **clean project не помогает**

UPD_2: "Profile app" - тоже нажимал. Точно те же самые логи ошибки, что и было. Изменений нет

Comment: а вы точно импортировали R?   import your_application_package_name.R

Comment: Признаться, не уверен, что понимаю о чём Вы. Как именно и откуда его надо импортировать?

Comment: Сверху кода раскройте Import и посмотрите есть ли строчка наподобие такой: import com.example.danilshik.testapplication.R;

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Вот того, что Вы говорили нет. Подключается два вот этих файла
"import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;"

Comment: Нажмите на элемент R (где возникает ошибка), и нажмите сочетание клавиш Alt+ Enter и выберите Import class

Answer (score -1):

Вам необходимо импортировать R

Нажмите на элемент R (где возникает ошибка), и нажмите сочетание клавиш Alt + Enter и выберите Import class

Comment: "R" это встроенный класс ресурсов приложения, его не надо импортировать.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, без строчки import com.example.danilshik.testapplication.R; как раз будет ошибка, которая у автора

Comment: Нет такого варианта, с выбором импорта класса, только создать и переименовать

Comment: Класс R генерируется во время компиляции. Его не только не нужно импортировать, но и не получится.

Comment: Разве этот класс не должен создаваться как-то автоматически, при создание проекта? Не логично же будет, что в основном классе используется элемент, которого нет

Comment: Откройте в иерархии путь app-app>java, перед вами будет находиться 3 папки, скопируйте название и в конце добавьте через точку R. Должно получиться что-то вроде этого: com.example.danilshik.testapplication.R и добавьте этот код вверх кода со строчкой import